# MongoDB find regex matched keywords

Tags: mongodb

I have string field with values something like :

- path/xxxxxxx-2020-12-11.tgz
- path/xxxxxxx-2020-12-12.tgz

I have a custom JS function `fetch_date` which fetches date via Regex (using `RegExp`). I want to project a field date and then **group** on that field.

Expected sample output:

- {dt:2020-12-11, count:1}
- {dt:2020-12-12, count:1}

`$regex` operator can match the element but can't return matched keywords.

- Is it possible to find matched keywords using any native operator?
- Can I use JS function to project this new field and later `$group` on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$regexFind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/) worked for me.

Sample Query:

```
db.coll.aggregate( [
    { $addFields: {
       "dt": { $regexFind: { input: "$path", regex: <expression> } }
    } },
    { $set: { dt: "$dt.match"} }
] )
```